# Google Chrome can't be opened after running a browsing history cleaning batch file

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome, batch-file

I'm using this following batch file in an browsing history cleaning application in vb.net to clean up the browsing history for **Google Chrome**...

```
@echo off

set ChromeDir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data

  del /q /s /f "%ChromeDir%"

  rd /s /q "%ChromeDir%"

cls

   IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (

  @echo "Success Message"

   exit0

   ) ELSE (

  @echo "Error Message"

  exit 1001
   )
```

My problem is that whenever I'm running the application including the above batch file every time after running the Google Chrome gets unable to be opened even if I stop the application.After restarting the system Google Chrome can be opened and I found that the browsing history is deleted.But I don't want to restart my system every time to open Google Chrome after running the application.

I want to know that what is the problem in the batch file for which such a problem is arising....Please anybody help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go to Settings > Advanced Settings and uncheck the box for `Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed`. This should make sure Chrome closes properly once all its windows/tabs are closed and not have any stray processes running that force you to restart

Comment: Why don't you let Chrome handle that itself (CTRL+SHIFT+DEL) or use incognito mode so everthing gets delete afer use??